# Compare rows in df to rows in different df when columns and length of df is different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following data on a df1:

```
   id       date ... paid
0 123 2020-10-14 ... 30.0
1 234 2020-09-23 ... 25.5
2 356 2020-08-25 ... 35.5
```

There's some other information on df2:

```
   id payment_date amount type ...       other_info
0 568   2020-08-25   15.9 adj1 ...       some_words
1 123   2020-10-14   20.0 adj2 ...       more_words
2 234   2020-09-23   25.5 adj2 ... some_other_words
3 356   2020-08-25   35.5 adj2 ...  some_more_words
```

I need to compare every row on df1 against the rows on df2, on the specific columns mentioned. If they are an exact match, I'd like to add a column on df1 with the boolean result, or some str like "Yes". The final output should be similar to this:

```
   id       date ... paid new_col
0 123 2020-10-14 ... 30.0   False
1 234 2020-09-23 ... 25.5    True
2 356 2020-08-25 ... 35.5    True
```

Notice that the index is not important on any of the two dataframes, and their length is different (df1 is around 100,000 rows and 6 columns, df2 around 2,000,000 rows and 13 columns). The other columns don't matter in the comparison.

I've tried to use something like:

```
df1["new_col"] = ((df1["id"] == df2["id"]) &
                  (df1["date"] == df2["payment_date"]) &
                  (df1["paid"] == df2["amount"]))
```

But i get this: "`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`". I can't use something like "merge", because the columns are not the same, and df2 is too big, therefore, it'll take additional time. Also, I can't use `pd.Series.isin()` because each ID has lots of dates and amounts, and they must match perfectly. Dates and amounts are also the same for several rows, the difference would be when comparing the three columns mentioned.

I'm looking for a vectorized approach to this problem, or just an efficient way to accomplish this without iterating row by row on both dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` like

```
In [37]: df1['new_col'] = df1.merge(df2,
             left_on=['id', 'date', 'paid'],
             right_on=['id', 'payment_date', 'amount'],
             how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].eq('both')

In [38]: df1
Out[38]: 
    id        date  paid  new_col
0  123  2020-10-14  30.0    False
1  234  2020-09-23  25.5     True
2  356  2020-08-25  35.5     True
```